# latest authentication methods for Single Page Application

Tags: security, authentication

I am creating a web application and looking for guidance on authentication methods.  My first attempt was using webapi built in authentication.  Where the user submits username and pw, then token is returned.  Then on every user request, the token is then used.

I am wondering if there is something newer/better out now.  The webapi is on Microsoft Azure and I see Azure has a built in authentication and authorization support.  Is that one of the latest and greatest?

I am not trying to do that method where you can use your google or other existing accounts.

I realize this is a very open question so I am simply looking for methods that are standard these days and I will go out and research them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you name it authentication, but authentication is simply checking whether the user is who he claims to be. And you want to use credentials for this purpose.

So I suppose you want to know how to manage the users session afterwards. I'd go either for a good old session cookie (requires small amount of space on a server to remember the users session) or a JWT token (which can be session-less).

Rule of thumb: Use the first approach if you have one server you talk to. Use the second, if you have many.

One more note: authentication and session management are not topics where you want to use "latest" discoveries. They are highly security relevant fields where you want to have something proven.